# How to make checkbox exclusive in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In a multi-select question, how to uncheck all the selected options(if any) if last checkbox("None of the above") is selected?

Comment: do you have an example of the question? it will be easier to get an answer if you post some code...

Comment: What have you tried so far and where is the relevant source code to go with your question?

Comment: <html>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Reebok">Reebok<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nike">Nike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Puma">Puma<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Levis">Levis<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="none" value="none">None of these
</form>

<script>
var x=document.getElementByName("none");
if (x.checked){
document.getElementByName("brand").checked=false;
}
</script>
</html>

Comment: <html>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Reebok">Reebok<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nike">Nike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Puma">Puma<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Levis">Levis<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="none">None of these
</form>

<script>
var x=document.forms[0];
var i;
var j=x.length-1;

if (x[j].checked){
for(i=0;i<x.length-2;i++){
x[i].checked=false;}
}
</script>
</html>

Comment: <html>
<form name="checkboxform">
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Reebok">Reebok<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nike">Nike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Puma">Puma<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Levis">Levis<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="none" value="none">None of these
</form>

<script>
var x=document.checkboxform.none;
if (x.checked == true){
document.checkform.brand.checked=false;
}
</script>
</html>

Comment: <html>
<form name="checkboxform">
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Reebok">Reebok<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nike">Nike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Puma">Puma<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Levis">Levis<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="none">None of these
</form>

<script>
var x=document.checkboxform.brand;
var i;
var j=x.length-1;

if (x[j].checked == true){
for(i=0;i<x.length-2;i++){
x[i].checked=false;}
}
</script>
</html>

Comment: done!
<html>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Reebok">Reebok<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nike">Nike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Puma">Puma<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Levis">Levis<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="none" onclick="check1()">None of these
</form>

<script>
var x=document.forms[0];
var i;
var j=x.length-1;

function check1(){
if (x[j].checked){
for(i=0;i<x.length-1;i++){
x[i].checked=false;
}}}
</script>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

It depend of your html structure but i can you an example

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  
  if ($el.attr('id') == 'none' && $el.prop('checked')) {
    $('input').not($el).prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $('#none').prop('checked', false);  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="op1" type="checkbox" /><label for="op1">Option 1</label>
  <input id="op2" type="checkbox" /><label for="op2">Option 2</label>
  <input id="op3" type="checkbox" /><label for="op3">Option 3</label>
  <input id="op4" type="checkbox" /><label for="op4">Option 4</label>
  <input id="op5" type="checkbox" /><label for="op5">Option 5</label>
  <input id="none" type="checkbox" /><label for="none">None</label>
</div>
```

Comment: this is JQuery, i asked by javascript.

Comment: done! <html> <form> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Reebok">Reebok<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nike">Nike<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Puma">Puma<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Levis">Levis<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="none" onclick="check1()">None of these </form> <script> var x=document.forms[0]; var i; var j=x.length-1; function check1(){ if (x[j].checked){ for(i=0;i<x.length-1;i++){ x[i].checked=false; }}} </script> </html>

Answer (score 0):

You can get the common class name applied on all the checkbox and then use the following code:

```
 $('.checkboxCSS').click(function(){
     if($(this).attr('id') == 'none')
          $('.checkboxCSS').not(this).attr('checked', false);
    });
```

Comment: this is JQuery, i asked by javascript.

Comment: done! <html> <form> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Reebok">Reebok<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nike">Nike<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Puma">Puma<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Levis">Levis<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="none" onclick="check1()">None of these </form> <script> var x=document.forms[0]; var i; var j=x.length-1; function check1(){ if (x[j].checked){ for(i=0;i<x.length-1;i++){ x[i].checked=false; }}} </script> </html>

Answer (score 0):

You can take a help of below code:

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sqz75b9g/12/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectanswer"/>select 0
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectanswer"/>select 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectanswer"/>select 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectanswer"/>select 3
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectanswer"/>None of the above
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".selectanswer").click(function(){
        var currentParent = $(this).closest(".row");
        var checkboxGroup = $(currentParent).find(".selectanswer");
        if($(this).prop("checked") && $(this).index() == checkboxGroup.length-1)
        {
            $(checkboxGroup).not(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $(checkboxGroup).eq(checkboxGroup.length-1).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is JQuery, i asked by javascript.

Comment: @ManikManocha - why you have added `jquery` tag for your question. You are absolutely wasting others time. Please keep this in mind while posting your next question.

Comment: jQuery is written on top of javascript. So ultimately its a javascript... `:)`

Comment: haha i've posted few codes in comments above. can you please look at that and point out my mistakes? please

Comment: done! <html> <form> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Reebok">Reebok<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nike">Nike<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Puma">Puma<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Levis">Levis<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="none" onclick="check1()">None of these </form> <script> var x=document.forms[0]; var i; var j=x.length-1; function check1(){ if (x[j].checked){ for(i=0;i<x.length-1;i++){ x[i].checked=false; }}} </script> </html>

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("[name='none']").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')=="checked"){
        $(this).siblings().attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/moju8c75/)

Comment: this is JQuery, i asked by javascript.

Comment: done! <html> <form> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Reebok">Reebok<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nike">Nike<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Puma">Puma<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Levis">Levis<br> <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="none" onclick="check1()">None of these </form> <script> var x=document.forms[0]; var i; var j=x.length-1; function check1(){ if (x[j].checked){ for(i=0;i<x.length-1;i++){ x[i].checked=false; }}} </script> </html>